# Change Outlook's Default Address Book for multiple users

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, exchange, default-settings, address-book

When Outlook is configured with an Exchange account, the default address book is the Global Address List. As a result, when a user clicks the **To..** button in a new email, Microsoft Outlook displays the Global Address List instead of their personal Contacts folder. Sometimes this needs to be changed.

I know I can manually make Outlook use personal contacts by default by opening the Address Book in Outlook, clicking **Tools** > **Options...** and then **Start with contact folders**:

[image]

**How can I change this setting for multiple users, without logging in as the user?**  I'm open to Registry edits, Group Policy settings, etc. Anything but having to do it manually.

Environment:

- Windows 7 and higher
- Outlook 2007 and higher

---

What I've tried on my own:

- Reviewed the [Group Policy settings for Outlook](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030). I didn't see any that control the default address book.
- Google. Found [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-default-Address-Book-84c7be39-282a-4096-aeb8-89a2661a5162), but that's how to do it manually. And plenty of similar results.
- This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841870/set-outlooks-show-this-address-list-first-option), but it changes the **When opening the address book, show this address list first** option (not what I want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting **When sending e-mail, check address lists in this order** can be changed by modifying the following the Registry as follows:

**Key:** `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\[OutlookVersion]\Outlook\Profiles\[OutlookProfileName]\0a0d020000000000c000000000000046`

- *[OutlookVersion]* is the version of Outlook (e.g. `15.0`)
- *[OutlookProfileName]* is the user's Outlook profile name (e.g. `Outlook`).

**Value name:** `00033d1b` (type: REG_BINARY)

**Data:**

- `01 00 00 00` enables **Start with Global Address List**
- `02 00 00 00` enables **Start with contact folders**

---

#### PowerShell to Change Setting

Assuming Outlook 15.0 and a profile name of "Outlook":

Enable **Start with Global Address List**:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\0a0d020000000000c000000000000046\" -Name 00033d1b -Value ([byte[]](0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00))
```

Enable **Start with contact folders**:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\0a0d020000000000c000000000000046\" -Name 00033d1b -Value ([byte[]](0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00))
```

**Notes:**

- This can be changed while Outlook is open; the change takes effect immediately.
- Use of `Set-ItemProperty` assumes the value `00033d1b` already exists in the Registry.
- Credit to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26460742/2227908) for explaining how to use the `[byte[]]` syntax.
- Credit to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39098042/programmatically-configure-outlooks-options-for-address-lists/41381579#41381579) for providing a starting place for finding this answer.

Answer (score 0):

(same as above)

Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office[OutlookVersion]\Outlook\Profiles[OutlookProfileName]\0a0d020000000000c000000000000046

```
[OutlookVersion] is the version of Outlook (e.g. 15.0)
[OutlookProfileName] is the user's Outlook profile name (e.g. Outlook).
```

The key that worked for me was: `000b3d1c`

`GAL = 00 00`

if set to `01 00`,  then offline address book

Comment: This answer has zero context... please add more detail, as I'm assuming you're referring to a registry key's value, but you included no key.